# Multimeter precision on low battery

Tags: multimeter, battery-operated, precision

Recently I measured some voltages with my cheap digital multimeter while it was showing the low battery indicator. Later I purchased a replacement battery and decided to redo my measurements. I found that the previous results were off by about 30%, so I learned that I should not do any measurements when the low battery indicator is shown.

But then a question popped up: what if the multimeter battery is only 50% discharged? Will I get accurate measurements when the battery voltage is above certain threshold, or will I get an error proportional to the multimeter battery voltage without any indication?

Comment: *But then a question popped up: what if the multimeter battery is only 50% discharged?* There you already assume that a 50% depleted battery will have such a significant voltage drop that it would influence the multimeter. Look up some battery discharge curves and note how at 50% of the battery's life the voltage has not dropped significantly yet.

Comment: Best to use meter which either refuse to function if not able to do so properly eg some Flukes, or at a minimum have a low battery indicator that shows when the manufacturer considers the n\meter cannot function correctly.

Comment: Comment on re-open. This isn't an opinion question, or needn't be. The answer can be arrived at by measurement, and should be. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the detail of the meter. A cheap one is likely to be worse than a name brand one. If you can borrow another meter, I suggest you calibrate the suspect one against it, with varying battery voltage.

I did this with my meters, and was horrified.

I measured a fixed voltage, while powering the meter from a variable supply. I reduced the supply voltage, while monitoring the measured reading, and the state of the LO-BAT indicator.

Only one of my meters popped the LO-BAT before its reading deviated by 1%, and it was a cheap one.

All meters took 9v batteries. One meter quit before it got down to 7v supply. One meter kept going to less than 4v, and that was a different cheap one.

There's no need for guesswork about your meters. Measure them. Put a red sticker on any that can lie to you about their accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, **no**. The ADC reference will maintain regulation over a wide range of battery voltages- but when the battery voltage drops by a LOT the reference can no longer maintain regulation and accuracy begins to suffer greatly.

A proper meter should indicate low battery *before* that point, and preferably cut off the display entirely rather than display erroneous information, but it's a bit difficult to do that with the cost constraints of common handheld meters.

About the worst possible reference is to use the zener diode in an [ICL7106](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/intersil/documents/icl7/icl7106-07-07s.pdf) meter chip, as below:

[image]

The 6.2V zener has a constant current source in series which maintains the 6.2V down to the compliance voltage of the current source (plus 6.2V).

The [datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/intersil/documents/icl7/icl7106-07-07s.pdf) gives a rather lukewarm recommendation to the analog common as reference (emphasis added) however, it's free with the chip so often used:

> ...analog COMMON has **some of the attributes** of a reference 
>   voltage. When the total supply voltage is large enough to cause 
>   the zener to regulate (>7V), the COMMON voltage will have a low 
>   voltage coefficient (0.001%/V), low output impedance (15Ω), 
>   and a temperature coefficient typically less than 80ppm/×°C.

So, if the battery is **more than 7V** it should be a fairly good reference (by 1970's standards) but below 7V it may drop in voltage, causing the readings to increase, even to the +30% you have observed.

The LCD display in 3.5 digit meters is usually *static* drive and will work okay down to much less than 7V before fading too much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Vbat -Vref' difference. Usually 1.25 or 2.5Vref are used, and  scaled higher for ADc Vref' such as 5V

Comment: That's a tremendous generalization. Modern Multimeters shouldn't be using \$V_\text{bat}\$ for anything but driving logic – modern ADCs take external reference voltages for "full scale voltage".

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you misunderstand the point Tony tries to make. What Tony means is that it depens on how well the internal Vref can be kept at the proper value when the value of Vbat is dropping.

Comment: ty moustache for your infinite insight

Answer (score 0):

The DVM has an ADC inside it so the Analog Voltage can be shown on a Digital Display.The ADC has a voltage reference so full scale corresponds to the reference voltage .When the reference voltage falls full scale corresponds to a lower voltage .So this means that the DVM will read higher than the actual voltage .The reference voltage is supposed to be constant .They are often constructed with band gap devices which outperform Zener diodes.As the 9V battery voltage falls there will be a point where the reference voltage starts to fall also .This is where the meter starts telling lies.Dont run the DVM with flat batteries because then you will end up having to repeat your tests.The DVMs from reputable manufacturers remain truthful even when the battery is down to 6V .In the olde days the accepted rule of thumb in my neck of the woods was that anything that runs on dry cells should operate at 1 Volt per cell.